# Troubleshoot IIS 6 and Intermittent SQL Server Connectivity Loss

Tags: sql-server, iis, sql-server-2005, iis-6, troubleshooting

I am not a System Administrator, but I am temporarily trying to fill that role.

I have 2 Windows 2003 Servers.  1 server has my Microsoft SQL Database (SQL Server 2005) and the other is the web server with IIS6.

Intermittently (once every month or 2) the web server loses connectivity to the database server for a period of roughly 10 minutes.  It normally regains connectivity without intervention.

The website is set up to send me an email when there is a problem connecting to the database.  Within the email, I get the error code:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

I am able to access both servers during the outage.  I can go to my SQL server and open up SQL server without any issues.  I have looked in the EventViewer and do not see anything.

The last time that I had this issue, I stopped IIS6 and started it.  After doing this, the issue was resolved.  This leads me to believe that it is an issue with IIS and not SQL server.  How can I begin troubleshooting?

Comment: Connecting to SQL Server (using SSMS) from the SQL Server doesn't use TCP/IP, it uses Shared Memory so that isn't a valid test when the problem occurs. When the problem occurs you should test from the web server first: Can you resolve the name of the SQL Server? Can you ping the SQL Server? Can you telnet to the SQL Server port?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to look into this a little more using perfmon on the web server first and then the SQL server if nothing happens.  In my experiences, when something like this happens it's usually some bad web page code that causes this scenario.  However, the actual problem you're experiencing could be something completely different.